# Get json data to html

Tags: arrays, json

I have a json data from a mysql table that is queried from a php script. The json data is coming correctly like this:

```
{"result":[["id","name","origin_count","destination_count"],[1,"A S     Peta",0,0],[2,"Aachara",0,0],[3,"Aanjangaon",0,0],[4,"Aanjar",0,0],    [5,"Aathankarai",0,0],[6,"Abu",0,0],[7,"Abu Road",0,0],[8,"Achanta",0,0],    [9,"Addanki",0,0],[10,"Addavaram",0,0],[11,"Adipur",0,0]]}
```

I tried this code to get the data. But I cant able to access it.

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    $.getJSON("http://hex.com/cities.json",
    function (data) {
        var tr = data.result
       for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');

    // Indexing into data.report for each td element
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i].id + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i].name + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i].origin_count + "</td>");
    $('.table1').append(tr);
  }
    });
    </script>

    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Please help me

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Id  Name  Origin
undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined

Comment: the above  error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function like below

```
$.getJSON("http://hex.com/cities.json",
    function(data) {
        var tbody = $('.table1');

        $.each(data.result, function(i, e) {
            if (i > 0)
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                $('<td>').html(e[0]).appendTo(tr); // Id
                $('<td>').html(e[1]).appendTo(tr); // Name
                $('<td>').html(e[2]).appendTo(tr); // Origin
                tbody.append(tr);
        });
    }
);
```

**Here is Output from given json data**

```js
var data = {
  "result": [
    ["id", "name", "origin_count", "destination_count"],
    [1, "A S     Peta", 0, 0],
    [2, "Aachara", 0, 0],
    [3, "Aanjangaon", 0, 0],
    [4, "Aanjar", 0, 0],
    [5, "Aathankarai", 0, 0],
    [6, "Abu", 0, 0],
    [7, "Abu Road", 0, 0],
    [8, "Achanta", 0, 0],
    [9, "Addanki", 0, 0],
    [10, "Addavaram", 0, 0],
    [11, "Adipur", 0, 0]
  ]
};


var tbody = $('.table1');
 
$.each(data.result, function(i, e) {
  if (i > 0)
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $('<td>').html(e[0]).appendTo(tr);   // Id
    $('<td>').html(e[1]).appendTo(tr);   // Name
    $('<td>').html(e[2]).appendTo(tr);   // Origin
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Origin</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    $.getJSON("http://hex.com/cities.json",
    function (data) {
        var tr = data.result
       for (var i = 1; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');

    // Indexing into data.report for each td element
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i][0] + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i][1] + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i][2] + "</td>");
    $('.table1').append(tr);
  }
    });
    </script>

    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Just change the `'data.result[i].id' to 'data.result[i][0]` and for other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have a data structured like this

```
{
    "result": [
        ["id", "name", "origin_count", "destination_count"],
        [1, "A S     Peta", 0, 0],
        [2, "Aachara", 0, 0],
        [3, "Aanjangaon", 0, 0],
        [4, "Aanjar", 0, 0],
        [5, "Aathankarai", 0, 0],
        [6, "Abu", 0, 0],
        [7, "Abu Road", 0, 0],
        [8, "Achanta", 0, 0],
        [9, "Addanki", 0, 0],
        [10, "Addavaram", 0, 0],
        [11, "Adipur", 0, 0]
    ]
}
```

It is a valid JSON object, but what are you trying to do:

```
$(tr).append("<td>" + data.result[i].id + "</td>");
```

You try to access `i`th elemnent of array, but next, you try to get specific property, but you **do not have** properties in your subarrays. There are only values as array elements.

I suggest you to change (if possible) response format to similar to this, since it is much easier to iterate and access deeper nested data.

```
{
    "result": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Aachara",
            "origin_count": 0,
            "destination_count": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Aanjangaon",
            "origin_count": 0,
            "destination_count": 0
        } ... 
    ]
}
```

And then it would be possible to access values by a dot operator
`data.result[i].id`